# How to programmatically instantiate a python class and run a method with pydev?

Tags: python, class, methods, pydev

I'm not an expert in pydev, but I would know if it's possible to instantiate (from an eclipse rcp application) a python class and call its methods.
For example, I have the following simple python code  :

```
import math
import sys

class Test:

    def __init__(self, first):
        self.first=first

    def increment(self):
        self.first += 1
        return self.first

    def decrement(self):
        self.first -= 1
        return self.first

    def add(self,value1,value2):
        return value1+value2
```

I would like to instantiate the Test class and call the increment method or the decrement method. Notice: I agree that for the add method, it's not necessary to have a class but we need a simple example for how to use the API of PyDev and then to use the API with more complex example.

An other question is : how can I parse the python code from a file (*.py) with Pydev to find class and methods with its parameters?

Notice:
I know it's possible to do all this stuff with jython, but is it possible to do that in using Pydev (with an other Python interpreter, not only with Jython)? (because I need the 3.x syntax of python).

Thanks in advance,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Jython, you'll have to launch an external Python process that runs your class and communicate through sockets/files/xml-rpc or whathever fits better what you're trying to achieve.

As for parsing in PyDev, as it's unrelated, please open another question.